# Translating a Linear Regression from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I tried to translate a piece of code from Matlab to Python and I'm running into some errors:

Matlab:

```
function [beta] = linear_regression_train(traindata)
y = traindata(:,1); %output
ind2 = find(y == 2);
ind3 = find(y == 3);
y(ind2) = -1;
y(ind3) = 1;
X = traindata(:,2:257); %X matrix,with size of 1389x256
beta = inv(X'*X)*X'*y;
```

Python:

```
def linear_regression_train(traindata):
        y = traindata[:,0] # This is the output
        ind2 = (labels==2).nonzero()
        ind3 = (labels==3).nonzero()
        y[ind2] = -1
        y[ind3] = 1
        X = traindata[ : , 1:256]
        X_T = numpy.transpose(X)
        beta = inv(X_T*X)*X_T*y
        return beta
```

I am receiving an error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (257,0,1389) (1389,0,257) on the line where beta is calculated.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: @DineshPundkar Error added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are working with numpy arrays, not matrices as in MATLAB.  Matrices, by default, do matrix mathematical operations.  So `X*Y` does a matrix multiplication of `X` and `Y`.  With arrays, however, the default is to use element-by-element operations.  So `X*Y` multiplies each corresponding element of `X` and `Y`.  This is the equivalent of MATLAB's `.*` operation.

But just like how MATLAB's matrices can do element-by-element operations, Numpy's arrays can do matrix multiplication.  So what you need to do is use numpy's matrix multiplication instead of its element-by-element multiplication.  For Python 3.5 or higher (which is the version you should be using for this sort of work), that is just the `@` operator.  So your line becomes:

```
beta = inv(X_T @ X) @ X_T @ y
```

Or, better yet, you can use the simpler `.T` transpose, which is the same as `np.transpose` but much more concise (you can get rid of the `np.transpose line entirely):

```
beta = inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y
```

For Python 3.4 or earlier, you will need to use `np.dot` since those versions of python don't have the `@` matrix multiplication operator:

```
beta = np.dot(np.dot(inv(np.dot(X.T, X)), X.T), y)
```

Numpy has a matrix object that uses matrix operations by default like the MATLAB matrix.  *Do not use it!*  It is slow, poorly-supported, and almost never what you really want.  The Python community has standardized around arrays, so use those.

There may also be some issues with the dimensions of `traindata`.  For this to work properly then `traindata.ndim` should be equal to `3`.  In order for `y` and `X` to be 2D, `traindata` should be `3D`.

This could be an issue if `traindata` is 2D and you want `y` to be MATLAB-style "vector" (what MATLAB calls "vectors" aren't really vectors).  In numpy, using a single index like `traindata[:, 0]` reduces the number of dimensions, while taking a slice like `traindata[:, :1]` doesn't.  So to keep `y` 2D when `traindata` is 2D, just do a length-1 slice, `traindata[:, :1]`.  This is exactly the same values, but this keeps the same number of dimensions as `traindata`.

**Notes**:  Your code can be significantly simplified using logical indexing:

```
def linear_regression_train(traindata):
    y = traindata[:, 0] # This is the output
    y[labels == 2] = -1
    y[labels == 3] = 1
    X = traindata[:, 1:257]
    return inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y
    return beta
```

Also, your slice is wrong when defining `X`.  Python slicing excludes the last value, so to get a 256 long slice you need to do `1:257`, as I did above.

Finally, please keep in mind that modifications to arrays inside functions carry over outside the functions, and indexing does not make a copy.  So your changes to `y` (setting some values to `1` and others to `-1`), will affect `traindata` outside of your function.  If you want to avoid that, you need to make a copy before you make your changes:

```
y = traindata[:, 0].copy()
```